# Change of variables (proof of Morrey's inequality)

Tags: functional-analysis, integration

I have one question of one of the steps in the proof of Morrey's inequality in Evans second edition. 
That is in the changing of variable, with $y = x+tw$, $t = |x-y|$. Evans do the following:

$$ \int_0^s \int_{ \partial B(0,1) } |Du(x+tw)|dS(w) dt = \int_0^s \int_{\partial B(x,t)} \frac{|Du(y)|}{t^{n-1}}dS(y)dt.$$

Here $x,y,w \in \mathbb{R}^n$.I'm wondering how the $t^{n-1}$ appears in the denominator? There should be a jacobian, due to the change of variable, however I am unsure how this is treated in the change from $dS(w)$ to $dS(y)$.

Comment: it is without doubt coming from the Jacobian. If $f(w) = x + tw$, then calculate the Jacobian of $f$ from its definition.

Comment: yes, but why $ \frac{1}{t^{n-1}} $ ?

Comment: if these were single variables, you would get $dy = tdw$. $(n - 1)$ because happening on a surface.

Comment: Like MBM says, that is the way the surface elements changes under scaling. To prove it rigorously you should use polar coordinates. Otherwise just content yourself with the intuitive idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hausdorff Measure and The Coarea formula are what you need to make it really rigorous. The  Coarea formula though is in the appendix and working through Evans PDE book I reckon you can take it as a sort of 'black box' result. As a reference though have a look at sections 2 and 3 of Gariepy and Evans book: Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions.

In Evans's notation in the surface integral over an n-dim ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ the $dS$ corresponds to the Hausdorff $n-1$ dim measure of the surface of the ball. In other words, you get the surface area of the $n$ dim ball. In particular,
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(\partial B(x, r))=\int_{\partial B(x, r)}\mathrm{d}S=n\alpha(n)r^{n-1}.
\end{equation}

So I guess one way to 'see' the change of variables which is just a scaling map in your work above is as follows. We have
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{s}\int_{\partial B(0, 1)}\vert Du(x+tw)\vert\mathrm{d}S\mathrm{d}t= \int_{0}^{s}\int_{\partial B(0, 1)}\vert Du(x+tw)\vert\frac{t^{n-1}}{t^{n-1}}\mathrm{d}S\mathrm{d}t.
\end{equation}
Let $y=x+tw$, then
\begin{equation}
t=\vert x-y\vert\Rightarrow y\in\partial B(x, t)
\end{equation}
and (symbolically)
\begin{equation}
dS_y=n\alpha(n)t^{n-1}=t^{n-1}dS
\end{equation}
because
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(\partial B(0, 1))=\int_{\partial B(0, 1)}\mathrm{d}S=n\alpha(n).
\end{equation}
So now putting everything together we have
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{s}\int_{\partial B(0, 1)}\vert Du(x+tw)\frac{t^{n-1}}{t^{n-1}}\mathrm{d}S\mathrm{d}t=\int_{0}^{s}\int_{\partial B(x, t)}\vert\frac{\vert Du(y)\vert}{t^{n-1}}\mathrm{d}S_y\mathrm{d}t
\end{equation}

Comment: Note that $\frac{t^{n-1}}{t^{n-1}}$ doesn't change anything because we are just multiplying the integrand by one.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! :)